# Inconsistent strict aliasing rules

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

I have the following program where I initialize two buffers in a seemingly fast way by casting the 8-bit buffer to 32 and 64-bit values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a[2];
    uint16_t b[4];
} ctx_t;

void inita(ctx_t *ctx, uint8_t *aptr)
{
    *(uint64_t *) (ctx->a) = *(uint64_t *) (aptr);
}

void initb(ctx_t *ctx, uint8_t *bptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        *((uint32_t *) (ctx->b) + i) = *(uint32_t *) (bptr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t a[8] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef};
    uint8_t b[8] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef};

    ctx_t ctx;
    inita(&ctx, a);
    initb(&ctx, b);

    printf("a: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%02x", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\nb: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%02x", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

When compiling using GCC version 8.2.1, I get the following warning message:

```
> gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -fsanitize=address,undefined -O2 main.c
main.c: In function ‘inita’:
main.c:11:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  *(uint64_t *) (ctx->a) = *(uint64_t *) (aptr);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I read about the strict aliasing rules and it makes sense that something could go wrong by breaking this.
However, why am I not getting the same warning in the initb() function? Here I am also casting pointers and buffers to other sizes than what was declared.

The program works and yields the expected output:

```
a: 0123456789abcdef
b: 0123456789abcdef
```

If I fix the warning, by doing:

```
void inita(ctx_t *ctx, uint8_t *aptr)
{
    *(uint32_t *) (ctx->a) = *(uint32_t *) (aptr);
    *(uint32_t *) (ctx->a + 1) = *(uint32_t *) (aptr + 4);
}
```

Then, I now get the same result as before but without warnings.

Do I still have aliasing problems in my code (due to initb) or is it safe to do this?

Comment: I get the same on gcc 5.4.0.

Comment: Try to unroll the loop in initb(), you will observe the same warnings as for inita(). So it's just gcc not recognizing the problem when a loop variable is involved

Answer (score 2):

> Do I still have aliasing problems in my code (due to initb) or is it safe to do this?

Yes there is aliasing problems in both of your functions, and no it is not safe. There are no guarantees it will work or keep working. Compiler simply got confused when trying to detect it.

You need to explictly disable strict aliasing for not to risk compiler generating incorrect code. You also haven't taken care of potential alignment issues. When you fix those, you have also made your code harder to port.

Use `memcpy` instead:

```
void inita(ctx_t *ctx, uint8_t *aptr)
{
    memcpy(ctx->a, aptr, sizeof uint64_t);
}
```

Comment: If I change initb function in the same way as I changed inita, where I cast my a buffer to the correct size, is that still a problem then?

Comment: @Noxet Your changed function fixes access to `ctx->a`, but not `aptr`. You are dereferencing `uint8_t` as `uint32_t`. That is still invalid.

Comment: Of course.. Then it is a bit strange that the compiler only complains about one half of the problem. Oh well, now I know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

In the languages Dennis Ritchie invented, called C, and described in both editions of *The C Programming Language* (but extended to include 64-bit types) the one problem with the above code is that there is no guarantee that the automatic `char[]` objects will be aligned in a fashion suitable for access via 64-bit pointer.  This would not be a problem on x86 or x64 platforms, but would be a problem on platforms based on other architectures like the ARM Cortex-M0.

Dialects processed by implementations such as MSVC or icc that uphold the Spirit of C described by the Standards Committee, including the principle "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done", and make an effort to support low-level programming, will recognize that a construct of the form `*(T*)pointerOfTypeU` might access an object of type U.  Although the Standard doesn't mandate such support, that's likely because the authors expected that implementations would make at least some effort to to recognize situations where a pointer of one type was formed from an lvalue of another type, and thought such recognition could be left as a quality-of-implementation issue.  Note that there is nothing in the Standard that would require that a compiler given:

```
struct foo {int x[10]; };

void test(struct foo *p, int i)
{
  struct foo temp;
  temp = *p;
  temp.x[i] = 1;
  *p = temp;
}
```

recognize that an object of type `struct foo` might be affected by the actions of forming an `int*` with the address `foo.x+i`, dereferencing it, then writing to the resulting lvalue of type `int`.  Instead, the authors of the Standard rely upon quality implementations to make some effort to recognize obvious cases where a pointer or lvalue of one type is derived from a pointer or lvalue of another.

The icc compiler, given:

```
int test1(int *p1, float *q1)
{
    *p1 = 1;
    *q1 = 2.0f;
    return *p1;
}
int test2(int *p2, int *q2)
{
    *p2 = 1;
    *(float*)q2 = 2.0f;
    return *p2;
}
int test3(int *p3, float volatile *q3)
{
    *p3 = 1;
    *q3 = 2.0f;
    return *p3;
}
```

will assume that because `p1` and `p2` are different types, *and have no discernible relationship*, they will not alias, but will recognize that because `p2` and `q2` have the same type, they could identify the same object.  It will further recognize that the lvalue `*(float*)q2` is quite obviously based on `q2`.  Consequently, it will recognize that an access to `*(float*)q2` might be an access to `*p2`.  Additionally, icc will treat `volatile` as a "don't assume you understand everything that's going on here" indication, and thus allow for the possibility that an access via `q3` might affect other objects in weird ways.

Some compilers like clang and gcc, unless forced via `-O0` or `-fno-strict-aliasing` to behave in a manner suitable for low-level programming, interpret the Standard as an excuse to ignore obvious relationships among lvalues of different types except in cases where doing so would break language constructs so badly as to make them pretty much useless.  Although they happen to recognize that an access to `someUnion.array[i]` is an access to `someUnion`, they do recognize `*(someUnion.array+i)` likewise, even though the *definition* of `someUnion.array[i]` is `*(someUnion.array+i)`.  Given that the Standard treats support for almost anything having to do with mixed-type storage as a "quality of implementation" issue, all that can really be said is that compilers that are suitable for different purposes support different combinations of constructs.